# Failing to cast an object after a Datagram transport

Tags: java, serialization, casting, udp

This is an assignment I'm trying a few different ways to approach:

We have use UDP to emulate TCP. Earlier today I managed to get file transfer to work over UDP but of course iy has no error checking for resending of 'segments' so to I'm not trying to implement a message type class that takes an ID and some byte data.

Debugging shows me I am correctly making my message object and then I'm using public byte[] `serialize(Object obj)` to convert my object into a byte array for UDP Datagram transport.

On the Receive side it is crashing when I cast my deserialized object back to message.

CAST FAIL

```
Message receiveMSG = null;
    try {
        receiveMSG = (Message)deserialize(receivedPacket.getData());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UDPReceiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

DESERIALIZE METHOD

```
private Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
        return (Message)o.readObject();
    }
```

Can anyone spot why this cast back is failing? Thank you.

MESSAGE CLASS

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

    private int segmentID;
    private byte[] packet;

    public Message(int segmentID, byte[] packet)
    {
        this.segmentID = segmentID;
        this.packet = packet;
    }

    public int getSegmentID()
    {
        return segmentID;
    }

    public byte[] getPacket()
    {
        return packet;
    }
}
```

UDPSENDER CLASS

```
public class UDPSender implements Sender{
    private File theFile;
    private FileInputStream fileReader;
    private DatagramSocket datagramSocket;
    private int fileLength, currentPos, bytesRead, toPort;
    private byte[]  msg, buffer;
    private String toHost,initReply;
    private InetAddress toAddress;
    private int segmentID;

    public UDPSender(InetAddress address, int port) throws IOException{
    toPort = port;
    toAddress = address;
    msg = new byte[512];
    buffer = new byte[512];
    datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        datagramSocket.connect(toAddress, toPort);
        segmentID = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendFile(File theFile) throws IOException{
    // Init stuff
    fileReader = new FileInputStream(theFile);
    fileLength = fileReader.available();

    System.out.println(" -- Filename: "+theFile.getName());
    System.out.println(" -- Bytes to send: "+fileLength);

    send((theFile.getName()+"::"+fileLength).getBytes());

    DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    datagramSocket.receive(reply);

    if (new String(reply.getData(), 0, reply.getLength()).equals("OK"))
        {
        System.out.println("  -- Got OK from receiver - sending the file ");
        int length;
        while (currentPos<fileLength){

            bytesRead = fileReader.read(msg);

            Message message = new Message(1,msg);

            send(serialize(message));

            currentPos = currentPos + bytesRead;
        }
        System.out.println("  -- File transfer complete...");
        }
    else{System.out.println("Recieved something other than OK... exiting");}
    }

    private void send(byte[] message, int length) throws IOException {
    DatagramPacket packet = 
            new DatagramPacket(message, length);
    datagramSocket.send(packet);
    }   

    private void send(byte[] message) throws IOException {
    DatagramPacket packet = 
            new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
    datagramSocket.send(packet);
    }

    public byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(obj);
        return b.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

UDPRECEIVER

```
public class UDPReceiver {

    DatagramSocket socket;
    String filename, initString;
    byte[] buffer;
    DatagramPacket initPacket, receivedPacket;
    FileOutputStream fileWriter;
    int bytesReceived, bytesToReceive;

    public UDPReceiver(int port) throws IOException {
        // Init stuff
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        buffer = new byte[516];

        System.out.println(" -- Ready to receive file on port: " + port);

        initPacket = receivePacket();

        initString = "Recieved-" + new String(initPacket.getData(), 0, initPacket.getLength());
        StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(initString, "::");
        filename = t.nextToken();
        bytesToReceive = new Integer(t.nextToken()).intValue();

        System.out.println("  -- The file will be saved as: " + filename);
        System.out.println("  -- Expecting to receive: " + bytesToReceive + " bytes");

        send(initPacket.getAddress(), initPacket.getPort(), (new String("OK")).getBytes());

        fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        while (bytesReceived < bytesToReceive) {
            receivedPacket = receivePacket();
            Message receiveMSG = null;
            try {
                receiveMSG = (Message)deserialize(receivedPacket.getData());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UDPReceiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println(receiveMSG.getSegmentID());

//            System.out.println(bytesReceived);
//            send(initPacket.getAddress(), initPacket.getPort(), (new String("OK")).getBytes());
        }
        System.out.println("  -- File transfer complete.");
    }

    public DatagramPacket receivePacket() throws IOException {

        DatagramPacket packet =
                new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        return packet;
    }

    public byte[] receiveData() throws IOException {

        DatagramPacket packet =
                new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        return packet.getData();
    }

    public void send(InetAddress recv, int port, byte[] message)
            throws IOException {

        DatagramPacket packet =
                new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, recv, port);
        socket.send(packet);
    }

    private Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
        return (Message)o.readObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I finally debugged why the cast was failing. I was not taking into account the full byte size of my serialized object. I changed my receive buffer to `607` and the cast works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally debugged why the cast was failing.

I was not taking into account the full byte size of my serialized object. I changed my receive buffer to 607 bytes and the cast works correctly.